# javascript - Confusion over omitting 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain the following behavior? The first 2 examples work as expected, but why doesn't the last example work? I want to understand what's going on when I omit the 'this' keyword.  It seems like I was able to omit it in the first 2 examples.

**Alerts hello:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        hello = 'hello';

        function sayHello()
        {
            alert( this.hello );
        }

        sayHello();
    }
);
```

**Alerts hello:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        hello = 'hello';

        function sayHello()
        {
            alert( hello );
        }

        sayHello();
    }
);
```

**Error on the alert statement:** `Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined`

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        this.hello = 'hello';

        function sayHello()
        {
            alert( hello );
        }

        sayHello();
    }
);
```

Comment: Because there is no local variable called `hello`

Comment: It's the same reason this won't work `var hello = {x: 123}; alert(x);`.

Comment: I think more interesting is why first example works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov those are globals and there is no `strict mode`

Comment: @zerkms Then why does the first example work?

Comment: possible dup: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @WhiteHat—the OP's confusion isn't about scope, it's because the jQuery *$(document).ready* function sets *this* as *document*, so *this.hello* creates a property of *document*, not the global object (aka *window* in a browser).

Comment: But, if we have function inside function (inside function), 'this' refers to global object (window): http://jsfiddle.net/va77ccx7/1/  Not sure if i am right....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global variables are automatically made properties of the `window` object. And when you call a function without specifying any context (i.e. as `functionName()` instead of `something.functionName()`), the default context is also the `window` object.

Your first function is setting the global variable `hello`, which is the same as `window.hello`. The `sayHello()` function then alerts `this.hello`, which is also the same as `window.hello` because `this == window`.

The third case is different because your outer function is being called by `$(document).ready()`. When jQuery calls an event handler function, the context is the target of the event. In this case, `this == document`, so when you do:

```
this.hello = 'hello';
```

it's equivalent to:

```
document.hello = 'hello';
```

This doesn't set the global variable `hello`, so `sayHello` doesn't access it. This will work equivalently:

```js
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        this.hello = 'hello';

        function sayHello()
        {
            alert( document.hello );
        }

        sayHello();
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example when you say `hello='hello'` you are assigning a value to a variable `hello`.

So, if you `alert(hello)` it prints the variable.

---

When you say `this.hello='hello'` it assigns a property to the function. Since the function is a callback of `$(document)` it is assigning `document.hello`. In general however, it will just be the property of the anonymous function

Comment: An important note: in the first example it's actually `alert(this.hello)`